# ExcellentExport.js Manage Single Cell Width

Tags: javascript, html, excellentexport

I am using this to export to Excel https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport/tree/master

The problem is that I need a particular cell to be a certain width without that affecting the bottoms cells. Right now since my cell width has a long range String the bottoms cells are also affected by that width and become super long. I only need to make some cells width long but others to not be affected by it. How do I do that?